# Post on Facebook Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

It seems that the way of posting to your wall or friends wall has change. Can anyone understand how you can do it?

Comment: Are you using Rest API or Graph API? Which programming language do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed since when? Facebook seems to change things every quarter. Some of the latest ways are using the Graph API:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

or using the javascript SDK and the FB.ui method:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

```
FB.ui({
    method:'feed', to:1234567890123, name:'Check this out', link:'http://link.com',
    description:'very funny, a must see'
}, function(response) {
    //log response
}
)
```

Comment: It is not working! The FB Docs is a mess. Haw can you suppose to make something if they keep changing everything, ...

Comment: If you init the Facebook javascript lib properly, and use a real user ID for the "to:" value, then that code will work. I've been doing Facebook apps for about 3 years, it's extremely frustrating keeping up with changes.

Answer (score 0):

You just go to your friend's page and use the normal 'Share / Write something' functionality - it will appear on your friend's wall.